# How to prevent pyinstaller from giving error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, grep, runtime-error, pyinstaller

I have made a script that basically does what grep on Linux does for Windows.

```py
# grep.py

import re
import sys

class EnterArguments(Exception):
    pass


arguments = sys.argv

if len(arguments) == 2:
    contents = sys.stdin.readlines()
elif len(arguments) == 3:
    file = arguments[2]
    with open(file) as f:
        contents = f.read().split("\n")
else:
    raise EnterArguments("Arguments Were Not Given")

for line in contents:
    output = re.search(arguments[1], line)
    if output is not None:
        output = output[0]
        others = line.split(output)
        print(f"\033[92m{output}\033[0m".join(others), end="")
```

And when I make an executable using pyinstaller (`pyinstaller --onefile grep.py`) and run it using the Command Prompt I get:

```
$ grep.exe

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grep.py", line 20, in <module>
    raise EnterArguments("Arguments Were Not Given")
__main__.EnterArguments: Arguments Were Not Given
[1576] Failed to execute script grep
```

How can I prevent `[1576] Failed to execute script grep` from coming (is there any flags I can put)?

Comment: You're getting this error because you haven't provided any arguments.

Comment: But is it possible to somehow not get `[1576] Failed to execute script grep`

Comment: then you'll need to replace the ```raise``` line with something else.. like some sort usage screen..  though I don't know if that's what you want.

Comment: @ewong But is it possible to raise an error but not get `[1576] Failed to execute script grep`